# Ocaml : create a new list with list.lenght

Tags: ocaml

I try to write a program which sort a list of lists by ascending number (number of elements in a list).

I think I have to use `list.lenght` to retrieve the lenght of the lists, then I have to use `list.sort` on these values. I struggle to find how to create a new list with `list.lenght`. Not sure where to start.

Because it's not possible to use `list.length` with a list of lists, for example `list.length [[5;71;32] [33;32]];;`

Comment: You don't need `List.length`, and you can't create an "empty" list of a certain length before filling it. A list increases in length as it is filled (or rather, you create a new list with the old list and one additional element). What you need to do is loop recursively through the old list and its sublists, constructing a new list as you. I suggest you try doing it without sorting first, to reduce the size of the problem. Once you have that working, sorting should be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use List.length on any list:

```
# List.length [[5; 71; 32]; [33; 32]];;
- : int = 2
```

It's just that it doesn't really help with the sorting :-)

When you sort a list, you supply a comparison function. It can be any desired function that determines the desired order of the two value. You should be thinking about the comparison function that you want to use.

Comment: OK thanks I understand. So I should compare the number of elements in my list and then use `List.sort compare` to sort them. I still struggle to find of to return the number of the lists and compare them.